# I need help with this awk script

Tags: awk

The following data contains a variable number of fields per record with each row being a single record. Awk script that will add all of the fields for each row together and print the resulting sum per record.

```
rand.csv
1,3,5,8,10,11,54
1,2,3,4
15,18,21,42,37
1,1,1,0,0,3,16
4,1,8,0,4,6,13,16,17,20,8,6,4
13
```

This is what i wrote so far

```
BEGIN {

    FS=","

}

{
    sum = 0
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        sum+=$i;
    }
      print "Sum "$1""

    }

}

END{

    print "Sum of each row"
}
```

Comment: Are you using a shebang? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: Im not using shebang, its just returning an output

Comment: What does your error say?

Comment: this is what i wrote....BEGIN{


}


{

        {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)

          {sum+=$i

          }

        print sum;sum=0

}                                                                                                                                              what am i doing wrong because when i run  awk -f random.awk random.csv im getting an error. Im required to add a begin block

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the whole thing; just make like two changes to the original. One of those changes is that you need to remove the extra curly close bracket on line number 16. Then, make the other change and you should be good. i'll give you a hint: `$1` [usually refers to the first column in awk](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/any-easy-way-print-column-or-columns-from-text-file-using-awk)

Comment: thank you it worked.

Comment: Just a heads up: you won't usually get much help around here if you don't include the error in your question. Oh, and the error should have said `awk: ./random.awk:16: }` and `awk: ./random.awk:16: ^ syntax error` so line 16 of `random.awk` contains the syntax error: `{`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ more rand.csv 
1,3,5,8,10,11,54
1,2,3,4
15,18,21,42,37
1,1,1,0,0,3,16
4,1,8,0,4,6,13,16,17,20,8,6,4
13
```

---

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)x+=$i;print x;x=0}' rand.csv 
92
10
133
22
107
13
```

Basically only thing I changed is the `-F,` at the front and use command line.

Comment: Could you please show this with the begin and end. I just want to ensure im placing this correctly.

Comment: or just `awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)$1+=$i;print $1}'`